# matlab calling Findclass JNI crashes

Tags: java, c++, matlab, java-native-interface

I´m trying to call java methods from simulink Matlab using JNI. I developed a small code in C++ that calls a main method which only prints helloworld on screen as a first test but at the line that it calls to find the class, matlab crashes.
The C++ code is this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include "mex.h"
class MatlabAmbassador {

public:
    MatlabAmbassador ();
    //Destructor
   ~MatlabAmbassador ();
    void run();
      JNIEnv* create_vm() ;
    void invoke_class(JNIEnv* env);   
private:

}; // end class

MatlabAmbassador::MatlabAmbassador() {

}

MatlabAmbassador::~MatlabAmbassador() {

}


// -------------------------------------------------------------------------

JNIEnv* MatlabAmbassador::create_vm() {
    JavaVM* jvm;
JNIEnv* env;
JavaVMInitArgs args;
JavaVMOption options[1];
long status;
/* There is a new JNI_VERSION_1_4, but it doesn't add anything for the purposes of our example. */
args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
args.nOptions = 1;
    options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=C:\\Apps\\Projetos em java\\Portico\\Portico_Agent\\bin";
args.options = options;
args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;

 status=JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void **)&env, &args);
return env;
}
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------

void MatlabAmbassador::invoke_class(JNIEnv* env) {
jclass helloWorldClass;
jmethodID mainMethod;
jobjectArray applicationArgs;
jstring applicationArg0;

  mexPrintf("First\n");
    helloWorldClass = env->FindClass("Teste");  <--- MATLAB CRASHES HERE
    mexPrintf("second\n");
    if (env->ExceptionOccurred()) { 
 env->ExceptionDescribe(); 
 env->ExceptionClear() ;
 } 
     if ( helloWorldClass == NULL ) {
        mexPrintf( "%s%s\n", "Unable to obtain class reference for ", 
 helloWorldClass );
        return;
    } else {
        mexPrintf( "%s%s\n", "Sucessfully created class reference for ", 
helloWorldClass );
    }

    mainMethod = env->GetStaticMethodID( helloWorldClass, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");

    applicationArgs = env->NewObjectArray(1, env->FindClass("java/lang/String"), NULL);
    applicationArg0 = env->NewStringUTF( "From-C-program");
    env->SetObjectArrayElement( applicationArgs, 0, applicationArg0);

    env->CallStaticVoidMethod( helloWorldClass, mainMethod, applicationArgs); 
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
void MatlabAmbassador::run() {

 char str [80];

 mexPrintf(" INITIALIZING....\n" );
    JNIEnv* env = create_vm();
    invoke_class( env );


}
 // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Simulink Matlab has some methods to be used. One of this method is used to call the method run() described above. Here follows a piece of code:

```
static void mdlStart(SimStruct *S)
{
    char *buf;
    size_t buflen;
    int status;

   buflen = mxGetN((ssGetSFcnParam(S, 2)))*sizeof(mxChar)+1 ; // le o 3o parametro passado pela     funcao (nome do arq)
   buf = (char *)mxMalloc(buflen); // aloca memoria
   status = mxGetString((ssGetSFcnParam(S, 2)), buf,(mwSize)buflen);

 ssGetPWork(S)[0] = (void *) new MatlabAmbassador; // store new C++ object in the

MatlabAmbassador *c = (MatlabAmbassador *) ssGetPWork(S)[0];

c->run();
```

and the simple java code is:

```
public class Teste 
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

      System.out.println(" INITALIZING...");


  }
}
```

So, can anyone explain what am I missing or explain if there is a real problem calling JNI inside Matlab. Matlab is version 2011b and java version installed is JDK 1.0.6_45.

I´d appreciate any help as soon as possible.

Best regards
André Nudel
andre.nudel@gmail.com

Comment: Does `JNI_CreateJavaVM` succeed? Is `FindClass` called on the same thread?

Comment: Yes. JNI_CReateJavaVM succeeds indeed. FindClass is on the same thread.

Comment: How do you know it succeeds? You're not checking its return value.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `JNI_CreateJavaVM` succeeds? Your code is not checking the returned status code or resulting `env` value (which is not getting initialized, so it may contain garbage), and the crash is apparently occurring at the first attempt to use `env`.

If you're running this inside Matlab, the JVM creation may be failing because there's already a JVM running inside the process as part of Matlab's normal environment. The JNI documents say that "creation of multiple VMs in a single process is not supported" (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#wp636). If this is what's happening, `JNI_CreateJavaVM` will return `JNI_EEXIST` (-5). Even if that's not what's going on here, it's good practice to check the status codes returned from functions that can fail. The examples in the JNI documentation omit error checking "for clarity", but you should include it in code you're actually going to run.

Check the status returned by `JNI_CreateJavaVM` and print it out to make sure it's succeeding. And maybe initialize `env` to 0 so it's clear whether you got a pointer from JNI or just random data.

Comment: Good point. I didn´t realize that I was not checking the status. I´ll do it and let you know. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with Simulink, so I'm showing an example of a regular MEX-function instead.

As suggested by [@AndrewJanke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17397250/97160), I retrieve the existing JVM instance running inside the MATLAB process instead of creating a new one.

#### jni.cpp

```
#include "mex.h"
#include "jni.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    // get MATLAB Java virtual machine instance
    JavaVM *vm = NULL;
    int n; jint res;
    res = JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs(&vm, 1, (jsize*) &n);
    if (res != JNI_OK || n != 1) {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("mex:jni", "Couldn't find existing Java VM");
    }

    // get JNI interface instance
    JNIEnv *env = NULL;
    res = vm->GetEnv((void**) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);
    if (res != JNI_OK || env == NULL) {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("mex:jni", "Couldn't get Java JNI environment");
    }

    mexPrintf("using Java %d.%d\n",
        env->GetVersion() >> 16, env->GetVersion() & 0xFFFF);
}
```

I compiled the file using:

```
mex -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\include" 
    -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\include\win32" jni.cpp
    "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\lib\jvm.lib"
```

Run in MATLAB, I get:

```
>> jni
using Java 1.6
```

You should be able to extend the example above to call an external Java class. Note that I have not been able to pass data between MATLAB MEX-API and Java JNI API (by that I mean passing Java objects as they are to a MEX-function, or the other way around, passing some kind of `jobject` back directly as is to MATLAB, without conversion that is), as in:

```
>> x = java.lang.Double(1)
>> my_mex_jni_fcn(x)
```

The problem is that `mxArray` is an opaque type, so I do not know how to interpret the pointer returned by `mxGetData`